# Adding a check constraint to a table after it is full of data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with which I want to add a check constraint after it has already been created.  I did some googling and found some answers, but they don't appear to work.  Here is what I have tried:

```
ALTER TABLE noise_table 
    ADD CONSTRAINT chk_level CHECK (noise_level >= 0 and noise_level <= 0.1);
```

However, after running this statement, I can still update and insert outside of the checked interval, so it doesn't appear to be working at all.  What am I missing here?

Comment: MySQL does simply not support check constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented under [`ALTER TABLE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/alter-table.html):

> The `CHECK` clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

You could instead define `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE` [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html) that raise errors in the event that your criteria are not met:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER chk_insert_level BEFORE INSERT ON noise_table FOR EACH ROW
IF NOT (NEW.noise_level >= 0 AND NEW.noise_level <= 0.1) THEN
  CALL invalid_noise_level;  -- non-existent procedure, raises an error
END IF;;

CREATE TRIGGER chk_update_level BEFORE UPDATE ON noise_table FOR EACH ROW
IF NOT (NEW.noise_level >= 0 AND NEW.noise_level <= 0.1) THEN
  CALL invalid_noise_level;  -- non-existent procedure, raises an error
END IF;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Does MySQL not support raising real exceptions?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You're right, as of 5.5 it does with [`SIGNAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/signal.html).  I'm still stuck in the 5.1 world.  :(

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support check constraints.

Instead, MySQL "silently ignores" check constraints, so it doesn't display an error.

Comment: Interesting... Then how do you enforce constraints such as "column x can only be between values x and y"?  Surely several databases enforce such constraints...